# PTC thermister value

Tags: analog, circuit-design, power-electronics, circuit-protection, component-selection

I am trying to find out specifications of a thermister on which "10P" is printed. Its resistance at room temp. is 18 Ohms when the circuit is power off. How can I find out its specifications?[image: PTC Thermister 10P]

This is the approx. circuit where this PTC thermister is used. What is the purpose of using a thermister in this circuit?

[image: PTC Thermister circuit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The company who makes these is called [ampron](http://en.ampron.com/products.aspx?TypeId=67&FId=t3:67:3), its a Chinese company which means that documentation is hard to find, and they might have to be contacted directly.

[image]

As far as the use of the PTC it is most likely used as a current limiter for C20. As the current through C20 increases the PTC heats up and increases it's resistance. This would also change the filter pole of L1/C20 as temperature increases. Why it's there exactly, I don't know.